# Максимальная возрастающая подпоследовательность

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Есть задача, реализовать алгоритм вычисления максимальной возрастающей подпоследовательности алгоритмами стандартной библиотеки. Обычным способом реализовал (код ниже). Но с библиотекой algorithm практически не работал, поэтому представления не имею, как реализовать описанный алгоритм средствами данной библиотеки.

Читая описание алгоритмов, заметил, что они проходят по всему контейнеру, а в данном случае проход по всему контейнеру не подходит, т.к. нужно изменять итератор внутри цикла.

```
void Algorithm (vector<int> & input) 
// функция, вычисляющая макс.возраст.подпоследовательность по входящему вектору
{
    vector<int> max_seq; // для хранения максимальной подпоследовательности

    for (auto iter = input.begin(); iter != input.end();)
        {
            vector<int> sub; // текущая подпоследовательность
            sub.push_back(*(iter++));

            while (iter != input.end()) // формируем текущую подпоследовательность
            {
                if (*iter > sub.back()) sub.push_back(*(iter++));
                else break;
            }

            if (sub.size() > max_seq.size())
                max_seq = sub;
        }

    Print(max_seq); // функция, которая печатает весь вектор
}
```

Не прошу написать за меня. Прошу объяснить, как вышеприведенный алгоритм переписать с помощью возможностей алгоритмов стандартных функций.  Может кто-то сможет подсказать, какими функции можно использовать?

П.С. в идеале можно прикрутить, чтобы ф-я возвращала ссылку на результат, но это не требуется.

Comment: на самом деле нужно искать пару элементов,  таких что a[i] > a[i+1]. И найти максимальное расстояние между такими парами. Для этого нет необходимости изменять итератор внутри метода. За один обычный цикл for сделать легко.

Comment: Да, @pavel прав. Все делается за один проход по принципу динамического программирования. Эта задача одна из базовых, на просторах интернета много готовых решений с примерами.

Comment: а вообще имеется ввиду непрерыная подпоследовательность? или любая? просто для любой подпоследоательности чаще задачу встречал.

Comment: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/longest_increasing_subseq_log - здесь читали? (:

Comment: @Bogdan Duminyuk, нужно найти возрастающую ПОДпоследовательность или подотрезок. Ваше решение ищет подотрезок... Это совершенно меняет задачу... Например для 1 9 2 8 3 Подпоследовательность: 1 2 3, а подотрезок: 1 9 или 2 8

Comment: Понятия STL в C++ более не существует. Это называется «стандартная библиотека». Не используйте аббревиатуру «stl» впредь, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать стандартный алгоритм `std::is_sorted_until`.

Вот демонстрационная программа, которая компилируется при использовании компилятора, поддерживающего C++ 2014.

Если она не будет компилироваться вашим компилятором, то нужно все `auto` заменить на конкретный тип, как, например,

```
std::pair<std::vector<int>::const_iterator, std::vector<int>::const_iterator>
```

Функция `longest_sequence` возвращает пару итераторов на начало максимальной возрастающей под-последовательности и ее конец.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>


auto longest_sequence( const std::vector<int> &v )
{
    auto p = std::make_pair( v.begin(), v.begin() );

    for ( auto first = v.begin(); first != v.end(); )
    {
        auto last = std::is_sorted_until( first, v.end() );

        if ( std::distance( p.first, p.second ) < std::distance( first, last ) )
        {
            p = { first, last };
        }
        first = last;
    }

    return p;
}

int main()
{
    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    const size_t N = 20;

    std::vector<int> v( N );

    std::generate( v.begin(), v.end(), [=] { return std::rand() % N; } );

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    auto max_sequence = longest_sequence( v );

    for ( auto first = max_sequence.first; first != max_sequence.second; ++first )
    {
        std::cout << *first << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Код успешно компилируется и выполняется при использовании онлайн компилятора Майкрософт.

Если вам нужно создать новый вектор из этой под-последовательности, то вы можете записать

```
auto max_sequence = longest_sequence( v );

std::vector<int> v1( max_sequence.first, max_sequence.second );

for ( int x : v1 ) std::cout << x << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Стандартный алгоритм `std::is_sorted_until` позволяет определить, что последовательность неубывающая. Если вам нужно определить, что последовательность строго возрастающая, то вместо алгоритма `std::is_sorted_until` следует использовать алгоритм `std::adjacent_find` с предикатом `std::greater_equal` или `std::less`

Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

auto longest_sequence( const std::vector<int> &v )
{

    auto longest = std::make_pair( v.begin(), v.begin() );

    for ( auto first = v.begin(); first != v.end(); )
    {
        auto second = std::adjacent_find( first, v.end(), std::not2( std::less<int>() ) );
        if ( second != v.end() ) ++second;

        if ( std::distance( longest.first, longest.second ) < 
             std::distance( first, second ) )
        {
            longest = { first, second };
        }

        first = second;
    }

    return longest;
}

int main()
{
    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    const size_t N = 20;

    std::vector<int> v( N );

    std::generate( v.begin(), v.end(), [=] { return std::rand() % N; } );

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    auto max_sequence = longest_sequence( v );

    for ( auto first = max_sequence.first; first != max_sequence.second; ++ first )
    {
        std::cout << *first << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Функция в этой демонстрационной программе ищет максимальную под-последовательность строго возрастающих по значению элементов.

Comment: form Moscow, у вас находится максимальный неубывающий подотрезок. (Равные элементы)

Comment: @BogolyubskiyAlexey  Да, вы правы. Это - дефект стандарта. Я уже делал предложение по изменению стандарта, чтобы выглючить функции типа is_strictly_sorted. В данном случае, если вам нужна строгая возрастание, то можно использовать алгоритм std::adjacent_find